# KendoUI Editor template for Drop-down not working for add items option

Tags: razor, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a KendoUI web Interface with 4 columns
1-Environment-name, 2-Environment-code 3- Server-details 4-Project-details
All of them are using **editor template dropdown** to show the values other than the Environment-name which is only a text field.
When i click on **Edit** and select the values from all three drop-downs, it perfectly sends the value to the controller and updates the database. But in case when i click the **Add New Item Button** the Server-details Drop down and Project details drop-down doesn't sent the values to the controller.

This is the cs-html File.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<EnvironmentPOCO>()
          .Name("Grid")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(d => d.EnvironmentName).Width(200).Title("Environment Name");
              columns.ForeignKey(d => d.EnvironmentTypeID, (List<EnvironmentTypePOCO>)ViewData["EnvironmentType"], "EnvironmentTypeID", "EnvironmentTypeCode").Width(150).Title("Environment Code").EditorTemplateName("_EnvironmentCodeDropDown");
              columns.ForeignKey(d => d.Server_ID, (List<ServerPOCO>)ViewData["Servers"], "Server_ID", "ServerName").Width(300).Title("Server Details").EditorTemplateName("_ServerDropDown");
              columns.ForeignKey(d => d.Project_ID, (List<SynergyProjectPOCO>)ViewData["SynergyProjects"], "Project_ID", "ProjectName").Width(400).Title("Project Details").EditorTemplateName("_ProjectNameDropDown");         
             // columns.ForeignKey(d => d.ServerID, (List<ServerPOCO>)ViewData["ServerDetails"], "ServerID", "ServerIP").Width(200).Title("Server IP")/*.EditorTemplateName("_ServerIPDropDown")*/;
             // columns.ForeignKey(d => d.ProjectID, (List<SynergyProjectPOCO>)ViewData["SynergyProjects"], "ProjectID", "ProjectDescription").Width(200).Title("ProjectDescription")/*.EditorTemplateName("_ProjectDescription")*/;
              columns.Command(d =>
              {
                  d.Edit();
                  d.Destroy();

              }).Width(200).Title("Action");
          }

          )

          .ToolBar(tools => tools.Create())
          .Sortable()
          .Pageable()
          .AutoBind(true)
          .Filterable()
          //.Scrollable()
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
                .Model(model =>
                    {
                        model.Field(m => m.EnvironmentTypeID);

                        model.Field(m => m.Server_ID);                  

                        model.Field(m => m.Project_ID);
                        model.Field(m => m.EnvironmentName);
                        model.Id(m => m.EnvironmentID);

                    })
                .Read(read => read.Url(ViewBag.ApiBaseUrl).Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
                .Create(create => create.Url(ViewBag.ApiBaseUrl).Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
                .Update(update => update.Url(ViewBag.ApiBaseUrl).Type(HttpVerbs.Put))
                .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Url(ViewBag.ApiBaseUrl).Type(HttpVerbs.Delete))
          )

    )
```

**_EnvironmentCodeDropDown Editor template**

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
                  .Name("EnvironmentTypeID")
                  .OptionLabel("Select Envrionment Type")
                  .DataTextField("EnvironmentTypeCode")
                  .DataValueField("EnvironmentTypeID")
                  .BindTo((List<EnvironmentTypePOCO>)ViewData["EnvironmentType"])
            )
```

**_ProjectNameDropDown Editor Template**
    @using List.Model.Model

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
                  .Name("Project_ID")
                  .OptionLabel("Select Project Name")
                  .DataTextField("ProjectName")
                  .DataValueField("Project_ID")
                  .BindTo((List<SynergyProjectPOCO>)ViewData["SynergyProjects"])
            )
```

**_ServerDropDown EditorTemplate**
@using List.Model.Model

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
                  .Name("Server_ID")
                   .OptionLabel("Select Server")

                  .DataTextField("ServerName")
                  .DataValueField("Server_ID")
                  .BindTo((List<ServerPOCO>)ViewData["Servers"])
            )
```

Comment: not sure what is the problem. Are you saying when you click Add new and enter the details for the record and submit, those new record details or not posted to the controller? what is the ViewBag.ApiBaseUrl for create method? are you using same URL for Create, Edit and Destroy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problem with the code above, there must be an issue in your database. Please check your database foreign columns must be set to not null. This will probably solve your issue.